# Live Graphs On Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, data-visualization

I have a live feed of data that represents network traffic for a remote machine. I would like to take this data and visualize it in a live plot in my webapp that is using Django, What is the easiest and fast way to achieve this.

What I tried so far: Generating scatter plots using matplotlib and updating the .png image on the webapp

Comment: you have tried anything ? atleast a google search ? show us what u have tried

Comment: @NIleshSharma I just update the question what what i have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/):

> RRDtool is the OpenSource industry standard, high performance data logging and graphing system for time series data. RRDtool can be easily integrated in shell scripts, perl, python, ruby, lua or tcl applications.

Some examples including web-based system monitoring applications of RRDTool:

- http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/gallery/index.en.html
- http://snm.sourceforge.net/
- http://munin-monitoring.org/

Answer (score 2):

A good option (I know from first hand experience) is using the Ajax update method with the Flot js library to plot live updating graphs. +1 for simplicity, extensible options, plugins and for the MIT license.

Look at an example here http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In the past when I've had to plot data in a browser, I've used [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/).  You could set javascript up to periodically poll a url on your django app that returns JSON encoded data to plot.